# EntityCommandExecutionException occures when loading embedded entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have a code that gets all products from my DB:

```
using (var entities = new DataEntities())
        {
            var products = entities.Products.AsQueryable();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameFilter))
            {
                products = products.Where(o => o.Name.Contains(nameFilter));
            }
            var result = products.Select(ProductBuilder.CreateProductDto);
            return result.ToList();
        }
```

**CreateProductDto** method:

```
        public static ProductDto CreateProductDto(this Product product)
    {
        return new ProductDto
        {
            Id = product.Id,
            Name = product.Name,
            IsEnabled = product.IsEnabled,
            KeyPairDto = new KeyPairDto()
            {
                Id = product.KeyPair.Id,
                EncryptedPrivateExponent = product.KeyPair.EncryptedPrivateExponent,
                Modulus = product.KeyPair.Modulus,
                PublicExponent = product.KeyPair.PublicExponent,
            },
        };
    }
```

It works fine on my colleaugue's machine. But I get EntityCommandExecutionException with the folloing inner exception: *There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.* when trying to access `product.KeyPair`.

Interesting thing is that if I refresh `product.KeyPair` via Debugger - it loads fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

to the provider part of the connection string within your entity framework connection string (i.e. the part the defines the data source, initial catalog, etc)